# leakage in StringBuffer.toString() casting issue

Tags: java, memory-leaks, stringbuffer

How to fix the issue of data/memory leakage in `StringBuffer.toString()` casting in Java.
I have found some tips like using a SAX parser for XML but need some more help.

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions.

Thanks in advance

```
xml.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
xml.append("<parent>");
xml.append("<child>");
xml.append("<Desc>");
xml.append(desc);
xml.append("</Desc>");
xml.append("</child>");
xml.append("</parent>");

response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());
response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

desc is the description of a field in the jsp been fetched from database.

Comment: which leakage? And what would it have to do with XML?

Comment: i am using a string buffer to make a xml and then .toString() to pass it as a parameter. when i cast the stringBuffer.toString() their is leakage of result  been reported. how to fix it?

Comment: being reported by what? What does the report say *exactly*? What's the *exact* code triggering this report?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? There 'was' an issue with `StringBuffer.toString()` in 1.4.1 but [this](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4724129) should be fixed in later versions?

Comment: JB - when people ask questions like this, you get the feeling that they don't actually want an answer.

Comment: its been reported by the code audit tool from the client side for my module. the code is above. the report says "Leakage of toString() result ("xml") via web page" at the syntax response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());

Comment: @Stephen C i think this place is not to increase the typing speed rather for some brainstorming results

Comment: I would really prefer using a `StringBuilder` over a `StringBuffer`...

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace of the error or exception whatever if you actually got that.

Comment: i dont have a stack trace as the issue been reported by a tool run at the client end an i am been provided with the report in pdf format having only the description message line no and the heading of the issue no other description. and regarding the use of StringBuilder is not thread safe ie not synchronized

Comment: what audit tool are you using? it doesn't look like it's talking about memory leaks, there must be some other explanation.

Comment: i dont know the tool or its description and also no other explanation is in the report. only thing that i know that their is leakage of data from this syntax. but i dot know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just validate the desc field using ESAPI

Answer (score 0):

> the report says "Leakage of toString() result ("xml") via web page" at the syntax response.getWriter().write(xml.toString());

I don't think it is talking about a memory leak.  A memory leak "via a web page" simply makes no sense.  I think it is *actually* complaining about what it thinks might be a security issue; i.e. a leak of potentially confidential information.

---

For the record, I don't think that that code contains a memory leak.

Comment: okay fine i accepts ! how could their be a leak of potentially confidential information from that syntax? please explain

Comment: @R.K.R - I honestly don't know.  I think you have got no choice but to get back to your client and ask them to explain to you what the report means.  Point out that you can't fix the problem if you don't understand it.